# jquery run function on href placed inside li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've a problem here trying to run a function from a a href placed inside list

Here is my Fiddle test so you can see what's appening

http://jsfiddle.net/Pluda/xK8BN/

So, this makes an accordion, it shows my items on ul click, but when I click on the li with the a href nothing happens...

What I'm missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this instead :

```
var paineis = $('#accordion > ul');

paineis.find('li').hide().end().on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    paineis.removeClass('activo').not(this).find('li').slideUp();
    $(this).addClass('activo').find('li').slideToggle();
}).find('li > a').on('click', function(e) {
    alert("ok, it runs");
    return false;
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xK8BN/3/)

Comment: ok, yours work, but what if I've to run diferent functions like per example "Painel 1" li as one a href, then "Painel 2" li's each have they're own functions as href?

Comment: @Pluda - Then you sort out the selector to select the right element, see this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xK8BN/11/). If you insist on running the function directly, and remember that inline javascript is not usually a good thing, then you could do = [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xK8BN/9/) ........

Comment: So, as you may see I'm not very good at this, I had the post_asp function inside the $(document).ready(function() and it didn't work. Now, with your change, putting the function outside it does, whats the diference? Is this a good practice?

Comment: Inline javascript and event handlers directly on elements that way is never good practice, but lots of people do it anyway, so that's up to you. The difference in putting it directly inside script tags is the scope. Every function has it's own scope, including the `ready()` function. You can of course declare the function name outside the `ready()` function, and define the function itself inside the `ready()` function, but it won't be ready until the `ready()` function has executed, and why you would do it that way is beyond me, but see this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xK8BN/12/)......

Answer (score 1):

I think it because how jsFiddle works, in the end jsFiddle does not emulate html document perfectly, and your `post_asp` function is not in window object... So even you write `<a href="#" onClick="post_asp();">Load de um asp</a>` it will not work.

Comment: I think you also deserve the "correct answer", sorry but but @adeneo was more complete, ok? Thanks